# ExtJS4 - All headers are not displayed in Grid Panel Header in Internet Explorer

Tags: extjs4

I am facing an issue with the extjs 4 grid panel header. There are four columns in my grid panel. Lets assume they are 1,2,3 and 4. The header 1 and 2 are not getting displayed but on slightest change in the width of the other displayed headers(3 or 4), all four headers appears back accurately. This issue happens only in IE. I tried in Chrome and Firefox and it worked fine. I am using IE8. Please provide your valuable input at the earliest. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anik

*this issue was solved by making the internet explorer document mode as per the IE-8 standard. Just add the following piece of code in the  tag of jsp page:*

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Answer (score 2):

We solved similar issue with adding following line to corresponding CSS

```
.some-class {
zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: i added following code to the css in the jsp but it didn't work out. I found that this is the class for the parent div tag.
.x-box-inner{
 zoom: 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try with Ext.viewport

```
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
  layout: 'fit',
  border: false,
  items: your grid panel
})
```